# Azure B2C Different Login Experience Based on Extension Attribute

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a scenario where it is not desired to have a sign in screen that combines login for local and social/federated accounts. The reason is that users can get confused and may not know which category they belong. The login experience should be thus: -

1. User provides email
2. User clicks Next
3. Read directory for value of extension_Type
4. If extension_Type equals "Internal", user is taken through federated login (IdP claims provider will be added in custom policy)
5. If extension_Type equals "External", user is asked for a password, and then clicks the login button.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You should start at the [IEF Wiki](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/azureadb2ccommunity.io/wiki). Also if this is possible with some preconditions on the journey steps, read/write operations at initial sign in/up and designing the page/forms (self asserted pages).

Comment: Thanks Jas. I had 2 sign in journeys - one only local and the other only federated. I went with deciding which journey the user gets right from the application.